# How to find the common difference in this case?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

The first and the last terms of an A.P. are $ a$ and $l $ respectively. If $S $ be the sum of the terms, then show that the common difference is $$\frac {l^2 -a^2}{2S -(l + a)} $$

Comment: Hint: $\,S = n \,\cfrac{a+l}{2}\,$ where $n$ is the number of terms.

Comment: @dxiv Your hint worked out great. Although I was aware of the formula,  but it didn't occur to me that the sum can be solved with that. Thanks once again.

Comment: Good work, and glad the hint helped.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

$ l = a + (n -1) d $
$Or, \; d=\frac {l-a}{n-1} $
$ Or,  \; d= \frac {(l-a)(l+a)}{(n-1)(l+a)} $
$ Or,  \; d= \frac {l^2 -a^2}{n(l+a) - (l+a)} $
$  Or,  \; d= \frac {l^2 -a^2}{2S - (l+a)} $ (as $S = \frac {n}{2} ( a+l) $)

A special thanks to @dxiv